# Error with insert statement from PHP to MS Access

Tags: php, html, database, ms-access, insert

I've successfully login with a user account and now i will like to insert records. As below is the code that has not been successful in inserting record.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Welcome: ". $_SESSION['role'];
?>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if (!$_POST['submit'])
{  
?
<html>
<body>
<br><br>
<fieldset >  
Add a new user 
<br>
<br>
<label for='username'>Username: &nbsp;</label>  
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'/>  
<label for='password'>Password:&nbsp;</label>  
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />  
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
Role: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<select name="role">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option VALUE="Administrator"> Administrator</option>
<option VALUE="Secretary"> Secretary</option> 
<option VALUE="Employee"> Employee</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />  
</form>
</fieldset>  
<table width=100%>
</html>
</body>
<?php
}
else
{
$conn=odbc_connect("employee","","") or die (odbc_errormsg());
if (!$conn)  
{
exit
("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO empTable (empID, password, Role, Days left in MC, Days left in   leave) VALUES" .
"('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[role]', 14, 14)";
$result=odbc_exec($conn,$query) or die ("result error ".odbc_error().'-'.odbc_errormsg());
odbc_fetch_row($result);
odbc_close($conn);
}
```

After clicking the submit button and when i refresh my database, nothing comes out. Why is that so? Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access doesn't like column names with blanks. You have to mask them with `[ ]`.

Change your `INSERT` query like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO empTable (empID, password, Role, [Days left in MC], [Days left in   leave]) VALUES ..."
```

Comment: Hi, Specht, thank you. Despite adding the bracket, the insert statement still does not work.

Comment: @Newbie: Try to output the content of the `$query` variable after building the `INSERT` statement. Does the statement look valid? Does it work when you execute it directly in Access (without PHP)? Can you show us the complete statement? I'd like to see it.

Comment: You will have to bracket password - `[password]`, or better yet, not use it, it is a reserved word http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738. It is also much better to just remove the spaces.

Comment: Okay guys. Solved it, it was indeed an error from the <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"> part, it only processed the ROLE, not the username and password. Nevertheless, the bracket did helped,  thank you specht and remou.